# error TS2339: Property 'title' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: angular11

**What can I do now please help me out....TIA**
**component.html`

```
  <mat-accordion multi="true" *ngIf="posts.length > 0">
      <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let post of posts">
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
              {{ post.title }}
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
      </mat-expansion-panel>
  </mat-accordion>
  <p class="text-info-mat-body-1" *ngIf="posts.length ==0">No post added yet!</p>`**
```

**{{post.title}},{{post.content}} "error TS2339: Property 'content' does not exist on type 'string'."**
**component.ts`

```
  export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    @Input() posts:string[]=[];

  }
```

`**

Comment: `posts` is declared to be a a `string` array, so `post` will be `string`, which doesn't have a `title` property as the error message tells you.

Comment: If you can edit the code It'll be very helpful